# select messages sent by user or to user

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, select, message

This should be fairly simple, however I am stuck with it.

when i do the query

```
SELECT * FROM `inbox` where toid=4 or fromid=4 order by time desc
```

, i get:

```
id  toid    fromid  message           time
23  48101   4   hello call me     12/23/2011 12:27
6   34584   4   hi there      12/22/2011 15:42
5   34584   4   how are you   12/22/2011 14:08
4   34584   4   say hello     12/22/2011 14:07
3   34584   4   whats up      12/22/2011 14:07
2   4   34584   nice picture      11/24/2010 0:00
1   4   2   this is very interesting!   12/23/2008 0:00
```

Now, I need to group the conversations between user 4 and other users each to one row with last message (like facebook messages do).

does anyone know the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide the sample output for the given input

Comment: can u provide what you want and what result you are getting right now?

Comment: i think you want view part not query you will fetch all conversation by user 4 but on click of top message the remaining messages should come some jquery stuff is it right

Comment: nope, we need a correct mysql select, not jquery.

Comment: I provided what we are getting now, and what I want is this:

id  toid    fromid  message           time
23  48101   4   hello call me     12/23/2011 12:27
6   34584   4   hi there      12/22/2011 15:42
1   4   2   this is very interesting!   12/23/2008 0:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22b89/4)

```
select i.id, toid, fromid, message, `time`
from
    inbox i
    inner join (
        select max(id) as id
        from inbox
        where toid = 4 or fromid = 4
        group by greatest(toid, fromid), least(toid, fromid)
    ) s on i.id = s.id
```

Comment: i think he want view part not query he will fetch all conversation by user 4 but on click of top message the remaining messages should come some jquery stuff

Comment: Clodoaldo, I tried this but it doesnt work ---  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where toid ='4' or fromid ='4' ) s inner join inbox i on i.t' at line 6

Comment: @Outlaw011 What do you mean by _it doesnt work_? An error is shown? The result is not the expected? Explain it.

Comment: @Outlaw011 I had the `where` after the `group by`. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo, I tried it... its almost there - the thing is that its returning 4 rows instead of 3, the rows 3 and 4 should be returned as one row as it is the conversation between the same users:      

1 4 2 this is very interesting! 2008-12-23 00:00:00
2 4 34584 nice picture 2010-11-24 00:00:00
6 34584 4 hi there 2011-12-22 15:42:57
23 48101 4 hello call me 2011-12-23 12:27:05

Comment: @Outlaw011 Ok I think I got it now.

Comment: Sorry but now - i got only two rows now, these: 
1 4 2 this is very interesting! 2008-12-23 00:00:00
23 48101 4 hello call me 2011-12-23 12:27:05

Comment: @Outlaw011 The SQL Fiddle I linked shows 3 messages. Is your data different from that one?

Comment: Hmm very strange. Yes, my message fields are longer - could that have any impact and cause this long row to not be shown??

Comment: #Clodoaldo - i populated the sql fiddle with original data from mysql and its showing 2 - i just can figure out why:    http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22b89/1

Comment: great job! just curious - what was it about? :-)